# Declare bash variables inside sql EOF

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, plsql

how to declare variable in bash command. See "?"
I thought we could almost run any bash statement with ! or host in front of line

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl << EOF

! export v10="Hi"                Doesn't work, why?
! echo $v10                      Doesn't work, why?  

! echo "Done"                 Works perfectly and also other bash commands

select * from dept;           Works perfectly
exit
EOF
```

Thank you

Comment: It probably launches a new shell for each shell command. The variable assignment won't exist in newly launched shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @jordanm says "probably" is exactly what is happening.  When you specify a host command from within sqlplus, a separate shell process is spawned, the command executed by that process,  then that process is terminated and control returns to sqlplus.  Any environment variables that are set in that child shell process are good only within it, so when it terminates, they are gone.

As for your specific lines that "work" and "don't work" .. "export v10="Hi" does work but there is no stdout display of the 'export' command, and as explained, that variable v10 ceases to exist once the child process completes and control returns to sqlplus.  The "echo $v10" also works, but since that is a new shell process, it has no value for $v10, so there is nothing to echo.

What are you trying to accomplish by setting enviornment variables from within sqlplus?

Comment: Hi Thank you for reply.I want to execute a group of host commands inside EOF in one block then exit the whole program if certain condition is met.

Comment: But as you can see, those host commands cannot communicate with each other, and they really cannot return anything back to sqlplus.  When I asked what you are trying to accomplish, I wasn't asking about the technique.  Step back from that and describe WHAT you want to accomplish, not HOW.

Comment: I want to check log file generated by sql statements without using UTL_FILE (via PL/SQL) so I will need to use bash command. UTL_FILE requires creation of directory object in database.

Comment: still too vague. WHAT log file created by sql statements?  If you object to using utl_file, I can only guess that is sqlplus's spool file.  What - specifically - are you looking for in the file and what - specifically - is to happen if/when you find it?  And what's wrong with creating a directory object in the database?  Also, the spool file has to be closed before it can be read.

Comment: I found it, all I needed to do was
<< EOF  
        whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
        whenever oserror exit failure rollback
        @scriptname.sql
        EXIT
EOF

Answer (score 0):

found it, all I had to do was

<< EOF
        whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
        whenever oserror exit failure rollback
        @scriptname.sql
        EXIT
EOF